# Quotes in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, quotes

Due to system integrity I can't use `"` in my VBScript. Additionally escaping the quotes won't work.

Is there a possibility to use different quotes? Single quotes don't seem to work.

Comment: Switch to JScript? What does "Due to system integrity" mean?

Comment: @AlexK. puzzling me as well to be honest, more explanation required.

Comment: This will need additional details to avoid closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, string literals in VBScript use double quotes. There is not any alternative quoting syntax.

But, of course, you can change this (with quotes)

```
Dim test : test = "test"
```

into this (without quotes)

```
Dim test : test = Chr(116) & Chr(101) & Chr(115) & Chr(116)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!